# CGRectContainsPoint for a UIButton during animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I am creating a UIButton that follows the UITouch point, I want that when I Keep pressing the touch and the animation boundaries reach my touch point I perform some activity there.

Following is the code.

I am always getting x,y 0 for the UIButton.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveAndStrech" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    if([touches count] == 1) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        self.uiButton.center = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    UITouch *touchTemp = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pCurrent = [touchTemp locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect currentRect = self.uiButton.layer.bounds;

    NSLog(@"Current Rect x:%f,Current y:%f",
          currentRect.origin.x,
          currentRect.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"TouchPoint x:%f,TouchPoint y:%f",
          pCurrent.x,
          pCurrent.y);

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(currentRect, pCurrent)) {
        NSLog(@"Touched....in rect");
    }
}
```

Regards
Sara

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
CGRect currentRect = self.uiButton.layer.bounds;
```

with

```
CGRect currentRect = self.uiButton.frame;
```

If that doesn't work, then

```
CGRect currentRect = self.uiButton.presentationLayer.frame;
```

Also, why aren't you using UIView animation blocks? It'd make your life much easier and your code much cleaner.

Comment: if I use self.uiButton.frame; it makes it like as soon as I tap it gives me a CGRectContainsPoint as true if I use CGRect currentRect = self.uiButton.presentationLayer.frame; it gives me an error that property not found

Comment: So use `layer.presentationLayer`. Go do some research, buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Several things. At first I thought you were missing the call to commitAnimations.

**DO NOT PUT MULTIPLE STATEMENTS ON THE SAME LINE!!!!** That is a very nasty coding habit that makes your code all but impossible to read.

Next, the old style beginAnimations/commitAnimations calls are outdated, and should not be used in iOS 4 or later. To quote the docs of beginAnimations:context:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

You should be using the new block-based animation calls (of the form (animateWithDuration:animations:)

Next, UIView animations cause the object being animated to move to it's final location instantly. They only LOOK LIKE they are moving to their final location over time. They also disable user interaction during animations by default.

If you want to figure out where the view appears on the screen at any given moment then you need to check the view's layer's animationLayer. I have a [**sample project on Github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo) (link) that includes a UIView animation of an image where you can tap on the image and the animation stops. This sample project shows how to use the view's layer's animation layer to figure out where the animation is located at the instant the user taps the screen.

If you want code that does something when the animated view gets to a certain point it would be more tricky. You might need to attach a CADisplayLink to your view (which will be called on each screen refresh) and use that to check the position of your animation and compare it to the current touch location.

Comment: checked on the sample, it does tell the things but still is there any alternate a quick one such that when the view reached touch point it sends a signal! or may be refer me something that I start with animation blocks and get to know how can I have this done!